# Django insert into list if doesn't contain it

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to insert into the notifications list, one notification of each type. and I have this:

Result from the initial query (I guess is a list with queryset), named `notifications`:

```
[<Notification: Should be first>, <Notification: New link>]
```

And the restriction that I have is:

```
   for(note in notification):
        if len(note.region.all()) == 0 and (note.notificationType.priority not in notifications):
        notifications.append(note)
```

My question is, how do I get inside the notifications list to get the attribute notificationType.priority to see is that number isn't inside `notifications` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question, you can try this :

```
notificationsPiorities = set([note.notificationType.priority for note in notifications ])
   for(note in notification):
        if len(note.region.all()) == 0 and (note.notificationType.priority not in notificationsPiorities ):
        notifications.append(note)
        notificationsPiorities.add(note.notificationType.priority)
```

Also, you may need to rename your variables. I can't tell for sure what are `notification` and `notifications`. One is the list you will display, and one is the list you retrieve with your query ?

Comment: Yes `notification` is `notification = Notification.objects.filter(**condition). order_by('notificationType__priority', '-start_date')`